# Display all records of a table unless I pass a key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there an other way to get all rows of a table using a stored procedure unless I pass the procedure a key?

If so, how can I code that in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData(@key int = null)
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (@Key Is NULL or id = @Key)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the COALESCE operator:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspMySprocName(@Key INT = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ID = COALESCE(@Key, ID);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a if condition and have 2 queries

```
**syntax:**  
    if (@key is null ) then  
        begin  
            select * from table1 ;  
        end  
    else  
        being  
            select * from tabel1 where field1 = @key ;  
        end  
    endif
```

The following link should help

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=146620